# How to build DCMTK 3.6.1 libs for iOS?

Tags: ios, dcmtk

I followed Russes' instructions found at http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3047&start=15

With a fresh copy of his "afab" git branch, I built Xcode project for x86 arch with the command line:

```
cmake -DIOS_PLATFORM=SIMULATOR64 -G Xcode ../dcmtk.public
```

or for arm arch with:

```
cmake -DIOS_PLATFORM=OS -G Xcode ../dcmtk.public
```

However, my Xcode project can't be successfully built because of, at least, the following errors:
[List of Xcode errors on ofchrenc.cc file (for eg. "No class named Implementation in OFCharacterEncoding")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epkxW.png)

The compilation with Unix makefiles gives the same errors in my case:

> Scanning dependencies of target ofstd
>
> 0% Building CXX object ofstd/libsrc/CMakeFiles/ofstd.dir/ofchrenc.cc.o
>
> dcmtk.public/ofstd/libsrc/ofchrenc.cc:518:28: error: no class named 'Implementation' in 'OFCharacterEncoding'
>   class OFCharacterEncoding::Implementation {};
>
> dcmtk.public/ofstd/libsrc/ofchrenc.cc:556:31: error: out-of-line definition of 'getLocaleEncoding' does not match any declaration in
>         'OFCharacterEncoding'
>   OFString OFCharacterEncoding::getLocaleEncoding()
>
> /usr/local/include/dcmtk/ofstd/ofchrenc.h:97:21: note: member declaration does not match because it is const qualified
>       const OFString &getLocaleEncoding() const;
>
> [...]
>   dcmtk.public/ofstd/libsrc/ofchrenc.cc:644:34: error: out-of-line definition of 'setConversionFlags' does not match any declaration in
>         'OFCharacterEncoding'
>   OFCondition OFCharacterEncoding::setConversionFlags(const unsigned flags)
>
> 19 errors generated.
>
> make 2: ofstd/libsrc/CMakeFiles/ofstd.dir/ofchrenc.cc.o Error 1
>
> make 1: ofstd/libsrc/CMakeFiles/ofstd.dir/all Error 2
>
> make: [all] Error 2

I don't understand what is wrong in my configuration:

- MacOs Sierra 10.12.2
- Xcode 8.2
- CMake 3.7.1 (I have the same issue previously with 3.5.2 version)
- GNU Make 3.81 (for Unix makefiles compilation)
- Apple LLVM version 8.0.0.8000042
- Darwin version of host: 16.3.0
- Building for minimum iOS version: 10.2 (SDK version: 10.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first error message but

> /usr/local/include/dcmtk/ofstd/ofchrenc.h:97:21: note: member
>   declaration does not match because it is const qualified const
>   OFString &getLocaleEncoding() const;

seems to indicate that you are mixing an old version of "ofchrenc.h" (stored in "/usr/local/...") with a more recent version of "ofchrenc.cc" (stored in your working directory).

Comment: Really well found! It seems that I had an old DCMTK version installed with brew a long time ago... 
I uninstalled it and now it works !
Thanks again for your help, I don't understand how I missed this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Since I'm one of the main DCMTK developers it was not that difficult for me to "see" the origin of the error(s). However, I personally have no experience with compiling the DCMTK for iOS (or any other Apple OS).